# Legends to ggplot with multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a gg path plot for multiple variables from a simulation and I'm trying to add a legend. I've tried multiple methods from previous posts with no succes. Using the code below, I only obtain the following [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VY1w.png) . The legend names should be the same as the variable name if that helps.

```
ggplot(Optimisation,aes(x=Iteration,y=get("Window width")))+geom_path(color="orange",size=0.3)+
  geom_path(aes(y=get("Horizontal offset")),color="blue",size=0.3)+
  geom_path(aes(y=get("Vertical offset")),color="green",size=0.3)+
  geom_path(aes(y=get("Window height")),color="purple",size=0.3)+
  ylim(0,5)+
  labs(x="UDI [-]",y="Energy need [kWh/m²]")+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=8),axis.text = element_text(size=7))+
  scale_color_manual(name = "Parameter",values = c( "Window width" = "orange", 
 "Horizontal offset" = "blue", "Vertical offset" = "green","Window height"="purple"), 
  labels = c("Window width", "Vertical offset", "Horizontal offset","Window width"))
```

Does anybody have a solution for this?

---

Comment: why are you using `get(...)` ? in the aesthetics, you should refer to the column name of your data.frame (I assume `Optimisation` but it isn't described) and the legend appears automatically. names and colors can be further changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the data it is difficult to reproduce your problem. See [How to As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for some hints.
Anyway, it seems, the issue is the structure of your data. Ggplot works best with '[tidy](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)' data. This example based on mtcars might give an idea:

```
    library(tidyverse)

    ## create an example data set - mgp, cyl and disp are the variables I'd like to plot with coloured lines:
    plot_df <- tibble(car_name = rownames(mtcars), mpg = mtcars$mpg, cyl = mtcars$cyl, disp = mtcars$disp)
        
    ## re-shape / "tidy" the data - I'm using pivot_longer from tidyverse:
    plot_df <- plot_df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(mpg, cyl, disp))

    ## and plot:
    ggplot(plot_df, aes(x = car_name, y = value, colour = name, group = name)) + 
        geom_line() +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```